# Error when loading the SDK manager: Error reading default devices

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, eclipse-adt

Whenever I try to open the Android SDK manager in Eclipse or Android Studio, I get this error:
Error: Error reading default devices
License file saxon-license.lic not found. Tried in file:/Library/Java/Extensions/saxon-license.lic, and classpath

I've been completely unable to find any help on the internet or even a hint as to why the SDK manager needs this file... does anyone know what I can do?

OS X 10.6.8, Java 6 if that helps

Thanks!

Comment: which version of java are you using ?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling the sdk and can you please tell me, when exactly the error comes ?

Comment: I've downloaded a fresh version of the SDK from google's developer website. The error comes whenever I try to open the sdk. I've tried in terminal (cd (...)/sdk/tools && ./android sdk), and it gives this:
net.sf.saxon.trans.LicenseException: License file saxon-license.lic not found. Tried in file:/Library/Java/Extensions/saxon-license.lic, and classpath

Comment: I've tried opening it through eclipse and Android studio, too - they both give versions of the same error.

Comment: are you talking about opening sdk manager ?

Comment: Oh... derp... yes that is what I meant. Sorry - brainfart! I've edited the question now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49094/discussion-between-pyus13-and-anonymouse)

Comment: I had a couple of jar files in /Library/Java/Extensions from a program called Saxon that I'd used to do XSLT verification. Removing them fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple of jar files in /Library/Java/Extensions from a program called Saxon that I'd used to do XSLT verification. Removing them fixed the problem.